# SQL Server Unique Constraint in a Category According To FK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, sql-server-2008-r2

The below code works great for creating `Unique Constraints` :

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT
            <constraintname> UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
                <columnname>
    )
```

I have a table named `Products` which has FK for another table called `Categories`. Imagine that the below list is Categories :

> Software
>
> Movie
>
> Music

What I need here is to have a unique constraint inside a category for my `ProductName` column inside `Products` table. For example, it is ok to have two same `ProductName` columns in a different category in `Products` table but not in the same category.

I am on `SQL Server 2008 R2`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple columns into a unique constraint or unique index definition. You need a composite unique constraint with two columns `ProductName, CategoryId`

Example Syntax

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT some_name 
      UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED(ProductName, CategoryId)
```

Comment: thanks. I figured I need a constraint with two columns but I am quite unable to figure it out how. Any code sample or resource?

Comment: @tugberk  -I've added example syntax to my answer. [See BOL for full details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx)

Comment: So cool @Martin. Thanks. I didn't try it but I'm sure it is the one.